# Big Query - Scheduled Query on yesterday ga sessions - empty Table

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, job-scheduling

This is my first question on StackOverflow, but I have already learnt a lot thanks to the community !!

Here is my BigQuery issue: I want to schedule a daily query at 5 PM to select in yesterday's ga_session_ table and create a new daily table from it.

SCHEDULED QUERY # standardsql

```
SELECT 
visitId,
date
FROM `my_table.ga_sessions_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

I have set up the query like this :

```
Destination table : interactions_{run_time-22h|"%y%m%d"}
Write preference : WRITE_TRUNCATE
Partitioning field 
Next import run : Nov 22, 2018
Schedule : every day 07:30 AM
```

***Results***: When I launch it on manual runs, it works well and  I have the table with my data. 
But, when I scheduled it, tomorrow morning, I have a table called interactions_20181122, at 7:30 AM, but I can not preview it, in Details, the Table is empty (0B).

I have tried to scheduled it without the Wild Table and the `_TABLE_SUFFIX` condition: the query works. So I guess the issue is on the `_TABLE_SUFFIX` condition.

Do you have something in mind ?

Comment: I think it's too early for table to be ready then. GA tables are uploaded between 6 and 11 am. try to push it back few hours.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that. So, the point is : we can not trust GA --> BQ importation to build daily dashboard based on it ? 

Google can not guarantee to deliver a table on a fix hour (like everyday at 6 AM?) ?

Thanks a lot AlienDeg

Comment: Unfortunately they can't. You can try temp tables but I don't know how of they are.

Comment: Thank you @AlienDeg